# Excel VBA runtime error 3706 provider MSDAORA cannot be found ADODB.Connection

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I wrote the following to connect to Oracle database using ODBC.
The references include the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

```
Sub testDB()

'   Database connections.

    Dim ExcelDB As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim ExcelRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ExcelSQL As New ADODB.Command

    ExcelSQL.CommandText = "SELECT item from item_master"
    
    ExcelDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA; Data Source=Garcia; User ID=RMS; Password=XXX"
    
    ExcelRS.Open ExcelSQL.CommandText, ExcelDB.ConnectionString, 2, 4
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That driver is not installed on your PC, or is not installed correctly.  Or the driver 32/64-bit version does not match the 32/64-bit version of Excel you're using.

Comment: The driver is installed and working correctly since I can do exactly the same thing from the data menu using getData -->FromOtherSources -> FromODBC -> DSN = Garcia

Comment: I don't know if 32/64bit matters from GetData, but it definitely does when using ADO.  Can you confirm that the installed driver matches the installed Office version in terms of 32/64-bit?

Comment: I checked and MS Office is 64 bit and the driver is 64 bit.  Thanks.  I think the problem may be in the provider parameter   ExcelDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=Garcia;User ID=RMS; Password=xxx"   I also downloaded the OLE driver and the connection works but I don't know the provider code for that

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/ first one there should work.  Have you checked your Oracle client install using (eg) TNSPing from a command line?

Comment: I found in another post that MSDAORA is not supported for 64 bit.  In the same post it shows how to connect using OLE DB.   It now connects but I am getting an invalid userid/password where I am passing the correct information. 
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=XXRMS)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gurmsdb.agarcia.com.mx)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=rmsuat)));Uid=rms;Pwd=xxx;

Comment: Try this format:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/#:~:text=TNS-less%20connection%20string

Comment: That worked.  Thanks a lot.  I really appreciate the help.  I have been working on this for a week. The correct string is: Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=XXRMS)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gurmsdb.agarcia.com.mx)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=rmsuat)));User Id=rms;Password=xxx;

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out